# Inno Setup tries uninstalling Delphi TService multiple times

Tags: delphi, service, inno-setup

I have a Windows Service built with Delphi 2010, and I'm using a Inno Setup installer for deployment.

It's mostly working smoothly - I correctly stop the service before uninstalls and upgrades, and restart it following installs.

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\MyService.exe; Parameters: "/INSTALL /SILENT"; ...

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {app}\MyService.exe; Parameters: "/UNINSTALL /SILENT"; ...`
```

However, I have one problem left: If I run the installer twice in succession, then the next time I uninstall it fails showing a Message Dialog : `Service XXX failed to uninstall with error: "System Error. Code:1060. The specified service does no exist."`

Logging shows that the "UninstallRun" section is being executed twice when the uninstaller runs. And the second time, it fails and throws the error message (from `TServiceApplication::RegisterServices`) because the service is already uninstalled. Pretty sure this is because of the way Inno Setup tracks multiple installations in `uninstall.dat`.

My 'hack' to fix this is to use the TService's `ServiceBeforeUninstall` handler, and `exit(0)` if the service isn't installed. This feels like a brute force approach - is there a smarter way of resolving the problem?

Comment: I agree that Inno should not be triggering the Uninstall logic multiple times, but I would also consider this to be a logic bug in `TService`, too. Apparently Borland (then CodeGear, then Embarcadero) never thought to update `UninstallService()` to ignore `ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` before raising an exception. If a service is being uninstalled and it does not exist, that should not be a failure condition, the intended result is already true.

Comment: BorCoDero has been updating the `SvcMgr` unit over the years with only very minimal code changes to account for OS/compiler/RTL breakages, not to fix logic errors, or add new features that have been repeatedly requested.  Oh well.

Comment: Read about `RunOnceId` in InnoSetup docs if you want run some unistall entries only one after several installations. http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection However it won't fix all scenarios, as service can be uninstalled by user/other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the built-in SCM wrapper functions in TService, use the SCM API, they will give you much more control on service management. I wrote an InnoSetup script years ago, you can find it [here](http://www.sandon.it/?q=node/9) - it's a while I don't update it, but it is still a starting point.

Comment: So that misuse of `Longword` is due to lack of missing types in Inno Setup at that time?

Comment: DWORD is, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx, a 32 bit unsigned int. InnoSetup uses PascalScript, which is not the best documented library. Sure, I could have used some types, but it was not my fault if Delphi took ages to release a 64 bit version - and AFAIK InnoSetup is still a 32 bit application.
Anyway. if I made some mistake somewhere or the code can be improved (and it can), feel the beauty of open source, fix it and publish the code. I always like how much the so called "Delphi community" is so eager to get some free code, far less to write and donate it...